# Errors running application in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having a problem with running my application in Eclipse. When I run my application it crashes immediately and says `Unfortunately (App name) has stopped.`

The application is a simple 2 screen ticket price application. First page just has a textview, imageview, and button. Second page has a text view, spinner, edit text, button and another textview. It's pretty much combining chapter 2 and 3 from the Android Bootcamp book.

Here is the logcat info:

```
02-15 14:31:28.061: D/dalvikvm(536): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-15 14:31:28.851: D/dalvikvm(536): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 67K, 3% free 9936K/10179K, paused 51ms
02-15 14:31:28.851: I/dalvikvm-heap(536): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.257MB for 494176-byte allocation
02-15 14:31:28.941: D/dalvikvm(536): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 3% free 10417K/10695K, paused 7ms+3ms
02-15 14:31:28.971: D/AndroidRuntime(536): Shutting down VM
02-15 14:31:28.971: W/dalvikvm(536): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.androidbootcamp.racetickets/net.androidbootcamp.racetickets.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at net.androidbootcamp.racetickets.Main.onCreate(Main.java:31)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
02-15 14:31:28.981: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  ... 11 more
```

**main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".Main" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Gateway Raceway"
    android:textSize="38sp" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:src="@drawable/gateway" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTickets"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:text="Find Tickets"
    android:textSize="32sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**tickets.xml (2nd page)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Gateway Tickets"
    android:textSize="38sp" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="Which Tickets do you want?"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/txtRacing"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:entries="@array/Type" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
    android:text="Buy Tickets"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnBuy"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:text="results" />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtRacing"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="How many tickets?"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
  </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main.java**

```
package net.androidbootcamp.racetickets;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {

  double costPerTicket=15.00;
  int numberOfTickets;
  double totalCost;
  String groupChoice;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final EditText tickets=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
    final Spinner group = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.txtRacing);
    Button cost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuy);
    final TextView result = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPrice));
    cost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        numberOfTickets = Integer.parseInt(tickets.getText().toString());
        totalCost = costPerTicket + numberOfTickets;
        DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat ("###,###.##");
        groupChoice = group.getSelectedItem().toString();
        result.setText("Total Cost for" + groupChoice + " is " + currency.format(totalCost));
      }
    });

    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTickets);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Tickets.class));
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Tickets.java**

```
package net.androidbootcamp.racetickets;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Tickets extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tickets);
  }             
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
Button cost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuy);
```

which you are calling in the main.java class will not work. Because your button is declared in the tickets.xml

i think you must replace

```
Button cost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuy);
```

with to get it works

```
Button cost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTickets);
```

Comment: Don't all resources get put into `R`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis   Yes but if don't inflate it before it wil not work. He has the button declared in tickets.xml and try to call it in main.java will not work until he inflates tickets.xml layout

Comment: I got it figured out. It wasn't just the button, that was just one of the things I got wrong in it.. I had everything for my tickets.xml in my Main.java instead of my Tickets.java. Thanks for starting me on the right path, Festus Tamakloe.

Comment: @ThomasHorner  your are welcome. if this helps you in any way just accept the answer.